# Bash: compare two files and change the output

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Trying to fix the output content with my script, but not work..
Let's name these two file as "File A" & "File B"
File A is content string like:

```
C Test aa.test.com
D Test bb.example.com
G Test cc.try.example.com
K Test dd.test.com
M Test cc.ee.try.example.com
O Test .test.com
T Test gg-1-2.example.com
U Test hh.example.com
X Test example.com
```

File B is:

```
test.com
example.com
try.example.com
```

Trying compare two files and to make output like:

```
C Test test.com
D Test example.com
G Test try.example.com
K Test test.com
M Test try.example.com
O Test test.com
T Test example.com
U Test example.com
X Test example.com
```

Here is my sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash
File_A="/root/temp/File_A"
File_B="/root/temp/File_B"

awk -v File_B="$File_B" -v OFS=" " '
BEGIN {
  while ( ( getline < File_B ) > 0 ){

     VAL = $0
     sub( /^[^ ]+ /, "", VAL )

     DICT[ $1 ] = VAL
  }
}
{
  print $0, DICT[ $1 ]

}' $File_A
exit
```

After output i still get the same content as File A, couldn't figure out.

```
C Test aa.test.com 
D Test bb.example.com 
G Test cc.try.example.com 
K Test dd.test.com 
M Test cc.ee.try.example.com 
O Test .test.com 
T Test gg-1-2.example.com 
U Test hh.example.com 
X Test example.com
```

or could be possible achieved from other command?

Comment: Yes, there is more than one way to do it. Your version seems to work though, so what's the problem?

Comment: The output is same as File A, means my command cannot find the match. think for a long time, couldn't figure out.

Comment: I didn't spot that. Maybe it would be useful to show the current output in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {arr[$0];next} {for (i in arr) {c=match($3,i);n=c&&(!b[$3]||c<b[$3])?i:n;b[$3]=c}$3=n}1' File-B File-A
C Test test.com
D Test example.com
G Test try.example.com
K Test test.com
M Test try.example.com
O Test test.com
T Test example.com
U Test example.com
X Test example.com
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but seems like the "try.example.com" will miss also

Comment: @JOSS Fixed.  I did not see that it could overlap.

Answer (score 3):

you can use this :

```
grep -of file_B file_A | paste <(grep -f file_B file_A | cut -d' ' -f1,2 ) -
```

Answer (score 2):

first sort `FILE_B` by line length and save it to `FILE_C`:

```
cat FILE_B | awk '{ print length(), $0 }' | sort -nr  | cut -d ' ' -f 2- > FILE_C
```

then run this command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{c=0;}FNR==NR{a[c++]=$0;next;} {for(i in a){if(match($3,a[i])){$3=a[i];print $0;next;} } }' FILE_C FILE_A
```

output:

```
C Test test.com
D Test example.com
G Test try.example.com
K Test test.com
M Test try.example.com
O Test test.com
T Test example.com
U Test example.com
X Test example.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but seems like the "try.example.com" will miss

Comment: Never use `cat` with program that can read files/data it self, like `awk`.  Use `awk '{ print length(), $0 }' FILE_B | ...`

Comment: @Jotne : why never use `cat` for pipe?!

Comment: I do not say pipe, but `sed` `awk` `grep` do read data itself, and it will be less and faster code.

Comment: To clean you code some: No need to declare `0` to a variable, so this can be removed `BEGIN{c=0;}`. No need for `;` before `}`, and `print $0` is the same as just `print` and the last `next` is not needed, so change all `;}` to `}`. And you get `awk 'FNR==NR{a[c++]=$0;next} {for(i in a) if(match($3,a[i])){$3=a[i];print}}'`